# IFrame empty box with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, html2canvas

I have a div which holds all of the data that I need to export as a pdf. In all of my test cases, exporting the page as a pdf has worked great except for this one case where a page has an iframe element that holds a pdf. When I export the page, the iframe content is just empty outside of its parent css (black background.)
I don't believe it is violating the cross domain policy as the iframe source and the page host are from the same domain. I am happy to use a different library if one exists for this problem but currently I am not aware of one.
I also dont need the entire pdf to be shown, window.print() would have been a solution for my task if it was automated beyond just opening a dialog.

I have tried myself to make edits to the properties and attributes of the iframe (with javascript) but nothing has made a difference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.